# Regex matches only once

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a regex that *should* rewrite `[img]foo.bar[/img]` to `<img src=foo.bar>` and in fact, it does. The problem comes in when I have two or more of those `[img]url.ext[/img]` in the string. Instead of matching each one separately, it matches the first `[img]` and the last `[/img]` and leaves the urls and tags in the middle as part of the `src`. My php code is `$newstring = preg_replace('%\[img\](.+)\[/img\]%', '<img src=${1}>', $string);`

a working example is https://www.regex101.com/r/mJ9sM0/1

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex matching an open and close tag and a certain text patterns inside that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368868/regex-matching-an-open-and-close-tag-and-a-certain-text-patterns-inside-that-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+?` instead of `+` for non-greedy match.

```
\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]
```

Demo https://www.regex101.com/r/zW9zJ0/1

`+` Will match one of more occurrence. Combined with `?`, it will match as least as possible (lazy).

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator is [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) by default, you need to use `+?` for a non-greedy match.

```
$str = preg_replace('~\[img]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/img]~i', '<img src="$1">', $str);
```

**Note:** I propose the above — recommending the `i` flag for case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are [greedy by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274990/why-are-regular-expressions-greedy-by-default). Try with [non-greedy regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/regex-match-non-greedy), i.e.

```
preg_replace('%\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]%', '<img src=${1}>', $string);
```

(Note the `?` after the `+`.)