# This regex is expected to end sooner, but ignores limiter

Tags: regex

RegExp:
`/<a href="(.*) target/gim`

Test string:
`<a href="/rss/images/" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/blooper/footer_rss.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS"></a>,<a href="https://t.me/blooper" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/blooper/footer_telegram.png?t=1" alt="Telegram" title="Telegram"></a>,<a href="https://discord.gg/lit" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/blooper/footer_discord.png?t=1" alt="Discord" title="Discord"></a>,<a href="http://blooper.media/"><img src="/themes/blooper/blooper.png" alt="blooper.media" title="blooper.media"></a>`

Result:
`<a href="/rss/images/" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/blooper/footer_rss.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS"></a>,<a href="https://t.me/blooper" target="_blank"><img src="/themes/blooper/footer_telegram.png?t=1" alt="Telegram" title="Telegram"></a>,<a href="https://discord.gg/lit" target`

Expected result:
`<a href="/rss/images/" target`

1 - What is the proper RegExp to select wanted string.
2 - Where did I go wrong? Am I having wrong assumptions about workings of the engine?

Comment: Perhaps you are wrong from the start [Regex and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `?` to make the regex lazy - that means it will match the shortest string possible:

```
/<a href="(.*?) target/
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/5vXsxo/1

Comment: I wonder why it's not default, it's exactly the most logical answer I would think of.

Comment: You can check out the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274990/why-are-regular-expressions-greedy-by-default) for more information